# Pandas df column has some value as dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, object

I have below pandas dataframe:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| {'all': 44} | {'all': 16} |
| NaN | {'all': 175} |

How do I extract numeric value from each column and replace NaN as 0?

I tried to use .values() on just first record:

```
value = df['A'][0]
value.values()

output: dict_values([44])
```

Not sure how to extract value from entire df?

Comment: please provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` for reproducibility (as [edit] to your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming real dictionaries, use:

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str['all']).fillna(0).convert_dtypes()
```

Or:

```
out = df.stack().str['all'].unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
    A   B    C      D    E     F    G
0  44  16  191  11153  351  3892  806
1   0   0    7     10  363     0    0
```

reproducible input:

```
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [{'all': 44}, nan],
                   'B': [{'all': 16}, nan],
                   'C': [{'all': 191}, {'all': 7}],
                   'D': [{'all': 11153}, {'all': 10}],
                   'E': [{'all': 351}, {'all': 363}],
                   'F': [{'all': 3892}, nan],
                   'G': [{'all': 806}, nan]})
```